# How I can implement sync calls to WCF services in SIlverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, synchronous

Sometimes I need to call WCF service in Silverlight and block UI until it returns. Sure I can do it in three steps:

1. Setup handlers and block UI
2. Call service
3. Unblock UI when everything is done.

However, I'd like to add DoSomethingSync method  to service client class and just call it whenever I need.

Is it possible? Has anyone really implemented such a method?

**UPDATE:**
Looks like the answer is not to use sync calls at all. Will look for some easy to use pattern for async calls. Take a look at [this](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2008/07/omg-silverlight-asynchronous-is-evil.html) post (taken from comments) for more.

Comment: Re your question: http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2008/07/omg-silverlight-asynchronous-is-evil.html

Comment: Has the accepted answer here really answered the question you asked?

Comment: It pointed me to do this the right way - i.e. accept async pattern and live with it. So - yes it did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the point; you **shouldn't** do sync IO in Silverlight. Stop fighting it! Instead:

- disable any critical parts of the UI
- start async IO with callback
- (...)
- in the callback, process the data and update/re-enable the UI

As it happens, I'm actively working on ways to make the async pattern more approachable (in particular with Silverlight in mind). [Here's](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/async-without-pain.html) a first stab, but I have something better up my sleeve ;-p

Comment: That's always a question for me - why? We can do sync calls to WCF everywhere (WinForms, WPF etc.) and we can run into same issues. What's so different about Silverlight?

Comment: (answered as a comment on your question)

Answer (score 2):

I'd disagree with Marc there are genuine cases where you need to do synchronous web service calls. However what you probably should avoid is blocking on the UI thread as that creates a very bad user experience.

A very simple way to implement a service call synchronously is to use a ManualResetEvent.

```
ManualResetEvent m_svcMRE = new ManualResetEvent(false);
MyServiceClient m_svcProxy = new MyServiceClient(binding, address);
m_svcProxy.DoSomethingCompleted += (sender, args) => {  m_svcMRE.Set(); };

public void DoSomething()
{
    m_svcMRE.Reset();
    m_svcProxy.DoSomething();
    m_svcMRE.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: If you run DoSomething on the main thread, your application will hang.

Comment: Thats right and thats why I did mention you shouldn't run it on your main UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a class that will let you synchronously call WCF services in SL:
 http://johnleitch.blogspot.com/2010/03/easy-way-to-synchronously-call-wcf.html

Answer (score -1):

Using SL4 building business application itself a wrong approach. I am facing problem with async call in SL4 client. Not only this issue. Once you go for a 15mins beeak after login SL application, after break you SL app can not retain  all data at all. Its happen sometimes very frequently.

Comment: I get the feeling the problem is more likely caused by your code rather than Silverlight.