# Why does ManualResetEvent fail to work in this synchronous call using Silverlight 4?

Tags: multithreading, silverlight-4.0, concurrency, asynchronous

Let's put aside for the moment, the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647481/how-i-can-implement-sync-calls-to-wcf-services-in-silverlight) of whether synchronous-like operations should even be attempted within the context of a Silverlight app. If I use ManualResetEvent as in the following code:

```
    static string result;
    static AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static string AsyncCall()
    {
        string url = "https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/silverlight";
        WebClient w = new WebClient();
        w.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(w_DownloadStringCompleted);
        w.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url), url);
        mre.WaitOne();
        return result;
    }

    static void w_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        result = e.Result;
        mre.Set();
    }
```

As you'd expect from reading [ManualResetEvent on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ssskfws%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), "When the controlling thread completes the activity, it calls the Set method to signal that the waiting threads can proceed.", when Set() is called in w_DownloadStringCompleted, control returns to the waiting thread that started waiting in AsyncCall. This is what happens when running this with .NET 4.0. The thread in AsyncCall gets blocked until the download completes and Set is called.

If I run the same piece of code in Silverlight 4, DownloadStringAsync will get called, yet control will never reach the w_DownloadStringCompleted callback. Once WaitOne() is called, that thread in AsyncCall just hangs there, and the thread which took off to process DownloadStringAsync never reaches the callback.   The only way I've seen a thread reach the download callback in SL4 is if the thread from AsyncCall returns from AsyncCall. So Set() never gets called.

**Why doesn't ManualResetEvent work as expected in Silverlight 4?** Why does it differ from .NET 4?
Is this maybe Microsoft's enforcement of the asynchronous design pattern?
Or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: If I hit Break All, I see that the debugger is stuck at WaitOne(), and that there is only a single thread in Threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The networking callbacks in Silverlight will always arrive *in the same thread* as they were originated. For example, if you make a WebClient.DownloadStringAsync on the UI thread (i.e., on a button click event), then the callback call will be queued to be delivered on the same UI thread. However, your call to `mre.WaitOne()` is blocking the UI thread, so the callback is never invoked, and the `mre.Set()` call never happens.

So yes, that's a kind of enforcement in the asynchronicity of networking calls - you really *can't* do synchronous calls, even if they seem to be synchronous.

Comment: do you mean that you can't do synchronous calls on the main UI  thread? Because I recently discovered how I can do a synchronous call if it's performed on a different thread. However in all cases it looks as though a ManualResetEvent.Wait() call made on the main UI  thread will block all asynchronous network calls, even if they were created on a different threads.

Comment: Correct, you really, really, really cannot do sync calls on the UI thread. That would essentially cause the application to "hang", which is exactly the reason for the decision of not allowing sync calls.

Comment: +1 for the added emphasis that you really, really, really cannot do sync calls.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be complete. When experimenting with this, even if I wrapped "DownloadStringAsync()" in a new Thread like so: `Thread t = new Thread((a) => client.DownloadStringAsync(uri)); t.Start();`, it still hangs just as before. Why?