# ManualResetEvent is not working with WCF and silverlight

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, silverlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does ManualResetEvent fail to work in this synchronous call using Silverlight 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147288/why-does-manualresetevent-fail-to-work-in-this-synchronous-call-using-silverligh)

I have a below code in MainPage.Xaml.cs

```
 ManualResetEvent wait = new ManualResetEvent(false);
 Service1Client wcf = new Service1Client();
 wcf.DoWorkCompleted += (o, ev) =>
 {
   int s = (int)ev.Result;
   wait.Set();
 };
 wcf.DoWorkAsync();
 wait.WaitOne();

//My other part of code where I'd like the value of `int s`.
....
```

Service1.svc.cs has the code below .

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
  public int DoWork()
  {
    return 5;
  }
}
```

Till the `DoWork` is completed I want my code to wait so I have written this code. Though after `WaitOne` instruction (Service1.svc.cs) method `DoWork()` won't be called at all. Application will stay there only doesn't do anything. I have worked on this before in another machine in SilverLight 4 and it was working as expected. Now I'm using SilverLight 3.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably causing a *deadlock* on the UI thread by calling `wait.WaitOne()`.

When the async operation is completed, it tries to invoke the `DoWorkCompleted` through the UI dispatcher. Although it will successfully queue the invocation, it will never dequeue since the UI thread is blocked on `WaitOne()`.

In my opinion, you should avoid this workaround and just do async calls.

Comment: Eren I created whole new application and tried the same still not working.I am using navigation application.