# WCF blocking call

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wcf

I am using WCF DataService I have a method:

```
[OperationContract]
    public List<string> GetAges()
    {
        return _registrationData.GetAges();
    }
```

on my client side, I instantiate it this way:

```
_registrationDataServices = new RegistrationDataServiceClient();
```

it now exposes a delegate

```
_registrationDataServices.GetAgesCompleted += GetAgesCompleted;
```

and a function call:

```
_registrationDataServices.GetAgesAsync()
```

the problem with this is that the call to the service will be asynchronous and the results comes in the delegate function, I want to be able to call the service and wait (block) until the results come back, how can this be done using WCF ?

I have to use a wcf, because I have a silverlight application that needs data from a database, the WCF is being called from a .NET assembly as my data access layer.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647481/how-i-can-implement-sync-calls-to-wcf-services-in-silverlight

Comment: Silverlight is made so that you can't block the thread. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Who created the RegistrationDataServiceClient class? Are there docs available online? Is there a .GetAges function that isn't async? What you actually want here is a non asynchronous version of the function.

Comment: @Nick The RegistrationDataServiceClient class is auto-generated by the Add service reference in Visual Studio. There is no synchronous version of the function.. it's explicitly discouraged.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I rather stupidly misread "WCF" as "WPF". And with that I think I'll get some of that desperately needed sleep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a very bad practice to call web service from a Silverlight/WPF application synchronously. The sync call would hang your UI until the web service call has ended, which will cause bad user experience.
However, if you're still up for it, [here is a very helpful link](http://johnleitch.blogspot.com/2010/03/easy-way-to-synchronously-call-wcf.html).

Comment: I completely agree with the bad practice comments. The internet is a funny beast and you should always assume that the worst will happen to your calls.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call it synchronously -- you will block the UI thread. Users usually think their software has crashed if the UI is frozen.

Ideally you would make a modal busy indicator that animates and shows 'progress' while you wait for the call to come back, and it goes away when you receive the Completed event.

Even if you were still convinced that blocking the UI thread was OK in your case, you can't actually call it synchronously! It was designed this way for a reason - go with the flow.

Comment: You can use a BusyIndicator object int the GUI.